# How to gracefully shutdown a spring-boot app after system kill signal

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, jvm

I am trying to make a java spring boot application shutdown properly after a system kill signal call on said application.

I want to let the application close all sessions/transactions when being shutdown via a system command.

eg. kill -9; kill -15; taskkill /f; etc

I have tried using a spring component shutdown callback as follows

```
@Component
public class ApplicationShutdown {
    private final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public ApplicationShutdown( ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext ) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void onShutDown() {
        applicationContext.close();
    }
}
```

I was hoping that killing the java process would trigger this callback, but it is not the case.

When I call taskkill /pid  (windows env) I am prompted that the process cannot shutdown without force.

when I call taskkill /f /pid , the application shuts down immediatly without triggering the spring callback.

Is it possible to have my application react a certain way to a system kill signal ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You are killing the process... What you are asking is much like I have a desktop PC, I pull the power cord but I want the system to ask me if I want to save the word document I was editing. Only a quit/abort `kill -3/-6` will do this, next to that Spring Boot already does a proper shutdown of the context so you shouldn't need this class in the first place. If you have a servlet app you can specify `server.shutdown=graceful` to allow your servlet container to cleanly stop. But not with a -9/-15 afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it is impossible to put a shutdown hook on a system kill sig. But it is possible to create a shutdown hook on application exit via ctrl c for example

```
Thread printingHook = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("In the middle of a shutdown"));
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(printingHook);
```

It looks like a good alternative